# Imagem e texto em LaTeX

Tags: imagem, latex, texto

Quando vou escrever em Latex tenho o seguinte problema que tentarei explicar com um exemplo:

Quando eu começo a escrever eu desejo que o texto siga a seguinte estrutura:
Texto1
Imagem1
Texto2
Imagem2
só que costuma sobrar espaço entre o Texto1 e a Imagem1 que cabe o Texto2 e então automaticamente o latex muda a estrutura para:
Texto1
Texto2
Imagem1
Imagem2

Como eu posso resolver esse problema para que meu documento siga a estrutura que eu desejo mesmo sobrando espaço?

Answer (score 1):

Use o pacote “float” e a opção [H] para suas figuras.

```
\usepackage{float}

 ...

 \begin{figure}[H] 
 \centering 
 \includegraphics{suafigura}
 \caption{Algum título} 
 \label{figxx} 
 \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
...
\end{figure}
```

mas o resultado é um pouco feioso...

Em alternativa:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
...
\end{figure}
```